# Optimal database schema structure strategy for a given situation

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, database-schema

I'm developing an unique application that uses a MySQL database and I'm seeking some advice on my database schema strategy before I go and implement it.

(Note: this is an abstract description of what I'm doing, the actual application i'm building is very similar in structure but not consisting of the actual components I name below.)

I'm building an application that will consist of:
1. Room Managers
2. Rooms
3. Guests

Every room manager is allowed to pick any number of rooms to manage, and guests can sign up to be in the rooms that are managed by a room manager. Guests can also select other guests to be part of their 'entourage' in the room. I've sketched out a diagram of the tables I'm thinking about using for this system's database implementation:

[image]

One other important thing to note is that this process will repeat itself once a week. Managers will pick rooms to manage, and guests will sign up to be in those rooms and bring an entourage of other guests. So as time goes on the sizes of the 'managers_rooms,'guest_reservations,' and 'guest_entourage' tables will increase the fastest. I want to give managers the ability to see all of the guests that have signed up to be in their rooms along with that guest's entourage, so that means i'll have to query the guest_reservations and guest_entourage tables (presumably with a join operation).

My question is: is this overall a good strategy, and will it cause problems as it scales and grows? I'm using MySQL with InnoDB tables and foreign key constrains + btree indexes where it would be appropriate. Any pointers? Tips? precautions? Thanks!

**EDIT2:**
I will be making my 'managers_rooms' table require a unique combination of 'managers_id, rooms_id, and date' as a key. 'date' using the MySQL DATE field.

Comment: TIPS: `MyISAM` tables doesn't support foreign key constrains; use `InnoDB`

Comment: You mention that the process repeats itself each week.  Consider creating an object/table (or at least indexed column) that represents each distinct time period so that when you are querying against reservations in a given time period you can make use of an index that will quickly find the rows in question.

Comment: @PPrice, my table has a column of type DATE for each record. Is this sufficient for sorting my records by week or do I need another column (maybe 0-51 for all the weeks in a year) as well?

Comment: Question - when you say that the process will repeat each week, do you mean that you'll be starting fresh? Or do you mean that you'll be adding to the existing table (which would eventually require you to add more rooms)? You made it sound like the latter in your post (as you talked about your tables growing) but you didn't talk about adding more rooms, which would eventually lead to a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: @caseyflynn Yep, a date for each record should work fine.  Just make sure that you have indexed those that will be used in query criteria.

Comment: @lunchmeat317, I mean more records will be added to the existing table. Every week managers and rooms are paired for a given day of the week, such as Thursday. Then next Thursday, a manager and room will be paired again. Each record in the table is essentially a pairing of Manager, Room, Date as a unique identifier. (I also use an id field BTW). So assuming I don't purge the records after a date passes, the table would grow as time continues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"good" is really hard to evaluate - the only criteria you mention are scalability.

In general, I'd say your proposal should work fairly well - the only refinement I'd suggest (similar to PPrice) is that if you have indeed got the concept of "period" - for instance a week - you might want to model that as a separate table in your database, and link reservations to that period.

This might reduce the need for date arithmetic when querying, and increase the likelihood of hitting an index; I'd only do it if this "period" concept is indeed a core business domain entity, though.

In order to evaluate your design, I'd think through the business logic and draw up the most likely queries you will have to support - "find all reservations for guest", "find all guests who have reserved a room from a given manager", "find all unbooked rooms for period" etc. and sketch out how you'd implement them using your design. In my experience, 90% of queries are obvious - 5% take some time, and 5% show a missing concept in the data model.

I'd also look at other evaluation criteria - maintainability is often overlooked.

Comment: thanks for the advice. You're right about 90% obvious, 5% take some time and 5%show a missing concept. I'm beginning to realize this as I continue working on my app.

Answer (score 1):

This structure should work fine.  Just be sure to have indexes on the columns that will be in your query criteria, like the date column.  Also, I would suggest that you pre-load a test database with a few million records and run your queries while profiling.  This will help find any scaling issues or missing indexes early on.